# Как изменить функцию замены url?

Tags: php

Есть такой код функции форматирования url, полученный из поля ввода

```
    function check_url($url)
    {
        global $EGN, $LANG;
        $url = strtolower(trim($url));
        if ($url != '')
        {
            if( !preg_match("#^([a-z\.\-_:\/]+[a-z]{2,4})$#", $url) || ( strlen($url) > 64 ) )
            {
                $EGN['errors'] .= $LANG['err_urlnotvalid'];
                $url = '';
            }
            elseif ( !eregi('http://', $url) )
            {
                $url = 'http://'.$url;
            }
        }
        return $url;
    }
```

после форматирования данной функцией в случае, если введена вот такая ссылка
`http://example.com`, то на странице появляется правильная ссылка,
но если была введена вот такая ссылка `example.com` (т.е., без `http://`), то почему-то к такой ссылке прибавляется текущий сайт, то есть, получается вот так: `mysait.ru/example.com`.

как можно решить эту проблему?

можно как-нибудь изменить функцию форматирования ссылки, полученной из поля ввода?

Comment: `global` вы серьезно?

Comment: Если вы начинающий, даже не смотрите такой код. Выбрасывайте его

Comment: C учетом того что данная функция вообще ничего не добавляет к url, возможно где то еще идет модификация адресов.

Answer (score 1):

Замените

```
elseif ( !eregi('http://', $url) )
    {
        $url = 'http://'.$url;
    }
```

на

```
}
if ($url && substr($url, 0, 4)!='http') {
    $url = 'http://'.$url;
}
```

Comment: не, не получается (  http://gtascript.ru/g/index.php?page=1

Comment: странно. функция-то - проще не придумаешь. может она вообще не вызывается?..

Comment: не, вызывается ,  единственно странно, что я вобще удалил эту проверку и результат не изменился =/